# Execute javascript on whole dom is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am working on my google chrome extension i wanted my script which is in  `"content_scripts"`
to be start executing after the whole dom(window) is loaded , i have tried to add `window.onload` on my javascript but it did not work?

Comment: use `"run_at": "document_end"` in your manifest.

Comment: @ParagGangil It defaults to `document_idle`, which is even later. To the original poster: it is unclear what you're asking. By default, content scripts inject after the DOM is fully loaded. However, they may be elements that are added dynamically after that. You cannot wait for that to happen, you'll need to watch for added elements if that's the case.

Comment: @Xan would you please give me a solution window.onload is not working